# Simulate sampling K values from uniform distribution with replacement

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, binomial-distribution, uniform-distribution

I am trying to reformulate sampling k values from a uniform distribution with replacement as a problem on deciding whether or not the nth value should be included in the sampled set.

In other words, I have D possible classes, each with equal probability. I want to construct a binary mask such that there are K non-zero values. I could run a sampling algorithm without replacement that will give me K distinct values, and thus a proper mask. The problem I have is that it's difficult to parallelize that algorithm, specifically on the GPU. Instead, I'm willing to relax the exact number of non-zero values to instead be on average K.

If I do that, then I think I can replace sampling from a D-class uniform distribution k times to sampling from a bernoulli distribution D times.

The probability of a single sample, K=1, is $p_n = 1/D$, and if I use that to sample from the bernoulli distribution D times, the expected value is 1 non-zero value.

In order to compute $K>1$, I want to compute the probability, for each $p_n$ that there is at least 1 success out of $K$ trials. The easiest way to do that is:

$q_n = 1 - p_n$

$z(k)_n = P(at\: least\: 1\: success : k)_n = 1 - P(all \; failures : k) = 1 - {q_n}^k$

And then, for each class in D, I sample from a Bernoulli distribution parameterized by $z_n$.

Concretely, let's say I have $D=512$, $p_n=1/D$ and I am computing $f(K)=\mathbb{E}\left[{\sum_n^DBernoulli(z(K)_n)}\right]$, for different values of $K$:

$f(1) \approx 0.99523$

$f(2) \approx 1.99271$

$f(4) \approx 3.98673$

$f(8) \approx 7.94724$

$f(16) \approx 15.7651$

$f(32) \approx 31.04493$

$f(64) \approx 60.2261$

$f(128) \approx 113.34335$

$f(256) \approx 201.61083$

$f(512) \approx 323.81925$

whereas I'd expect $f(K) = K$.

What is going on?

Also, the reason I am doing the sampling this way is because I want to extend this approach to sampling from a multinomial distribution instead of a uniform distribution. It's just easier to reason about the uniform distribution.

Comment: Forgetting GPU for a minute, is your basic goal to choose $K$ distinct values from a finite set of $D$ values, where the values are sampled without replacement and with uniform weights? (Otherwise known as "shuffling" ... for which Google suggests there would be many parallel shuffle algorithms)

Comment: Ultimately the goal is for non-uniform weights which prevents, to the best of my knowledge, shuffle-type operations. I only simplified it to uniform weights because it's easy to verify that $f(K) = K$, or in this case, refute the claim.

Comment: Probably it would be best to ask about your real question then. (BTW [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140787/select-k-random-elements-from-a-list-whose-elements-have-weights) on SO may be of interest.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, as I feel like I did ask my real question. There's something wrong with my model because even in the simplified case of a multinomial distribution with uniform class probabilities, I'm getting the wrong result. That said, you link does indeed seem useful, especially since it looks like it's trivially parallelizable. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded brusque. I had skimmed your question and gotten the impression you were asking about correctness of an approximation of a simplification of what I called your "real question" (I was tired). For something algorithmic like "GPU multinomial shuffle" (?), perhaps SO will have better resources (e.g. the "related questions" on my prior link seemed to also have some leads). It is an interesting question, but the only help I could provide is as above (i.e. guess some keywords and Google :) ). If you get an answer elsewhere though, please post it here!

Comment: Side note: I recently found (section 3.9.2 [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html)) a cute neologism for the single-trial Multinomial distribution that may sometimes be used: the "Multinoulli" distribution. (In analogy with Binomial/Bernoulli; I have to ask my Italian friends how they feel about that one!) Apparently the term was coined circa 2012, so it may not get many hits on Google yet!

Comment: I just implemented that link you posted, though instead of using quickselect I'm using thrust::sort, but the performance results are exactly in line with what I wanted. Thanks for the help. I will leave the question open, however, since the link doesn't address the math problem as originally posed. It's still a rather curious problem as far as I'm concerned.